# Visual studio keeps running the application after returning 0x0 ( clean return ) C++

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2013, console

I'm a beginner when it comes to C++ programming, but for some reason, whenever I debug my code and run the application ( i`m using SDL2 ) and close the window in Visual Studio, the orange bar is still there.

In other words, even though the window closed and I triggered SDL_Quit() and other clean up code, the IDE keeps running the application.

I tried using the SUBSYSTEM SUBSTEM/:CONSOLE and the normal Windows mode but no joy.

What does it mean? Oh and just a heads-up, the main() function returns a normal 0x0. I havent build in any error/debug modes to return yet.

```
int main()
{
Debug::setVerbosity(VERBOSITY);

App * app = new App("C:/dev/out/resources/settings/debug_settings.json");

// initialize all the core systems and subsystems
if (app->start())
{
    // the main game loop
    app->run();
}
// clean up all the objects, settings etc

delete app;

return 0;
}
```

Comment: You can just go to the `Break All` option in the debugger and check the call stack to see where it's stuck.

Comment: It`s not getting stuck anywhere.. The SDL window closes neatly.. It`s like the app is still running for some reason.

Comment: Maybe the app *is* still running.  Closing a window doesn't mean the application has stopped.  Is the `Break All` still available when you close the window?  If it is, the app is still running.

Comment: I tried, this time it cannot load all the symbols, in particular nvd3dum.pdb, very weird. Been searching for an answer but I cannot find any help on it. However, to summarize, I can still run it while it`s closed.

Comment: Uhm, i retrack my previous statement, I cannot run the break all after closing the window.